# Why doesn't my number record and print in my array?

Tags: java

Ok so I'm trying to make a pretty simple number generator with limits of 1 and 100. I've read over everything I can find online and can't figure out why my code doesn't record the numbers between 1-100 in the array then print the numbers from the array. When I run the code the number 36 gets printed over and over. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class NumberGen
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numbers[]=new int[10];
        Random gen = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            int number=gen.nextInt();
            while(number<1 || number>100)
            {
                number=gen.nextInt();
            }

            while(number<=100 && number >=1)
            {
                numbers[i]=number;
                System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            }


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: the expression (number<=100 && number >=1) is always return true, so you can not break the second while loop. You should remove the second while-loop, and just take 2 nested statement outside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the second while be an if? I'm pretty sure it's an infinite loop.
And why are you using the first while, well all of:

```
int number=gen.nextInt();
            while(number<1 || number>100)
            {
                number=gen.nextInt();
            }
```

when you could just int number=gen.nextInt(100)+1;

Comment: Either way, you don't need to validate that the number is between 1-100 because the first while or the gen.nextInt(100)+1 will only give you those results.

Comment: Ok I removed the first while loop and put in the number=gen.nextInt(100)+1. But I don't understand how this works. Could you please dumb it down a little bit for me?

Comment: when you give nextInt a parameter, it returns a random integer between 0 and that integer -1, so gen.nextInt(100) will give you a random integer between 0 and 99, but you want a random integer between 1 and 100, so you just need to add 1

Comment: [Java 7 nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) and [Java 6 nextInt friendlier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())… both explain there's an overloaded method nextInt()) and nextInt(int)

Answer (score 2):

You should use another flavor of `nextInt` -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

In your case:

```
int number=gen.nextInt( 100 ) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what is happening here:

```
   for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        /**
        *int number=gen.nextInt();
        *while(number<1 || number>100)
        *{
        *    number=gen.nextInt();
        *}
        **/
        number = 1;

        while(number<=100 && number >=1)
        {
            numbers[i]=number;
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
```

The while in the for loop is stuck in an infinite loop since 'number' never changes

What you should be trying to do is store the number in a single for/while loop then print in a seperate for/while loop

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
    //FYI gen.nextInt(100) generates a int from 0 to 99
    //store values
}
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
    //print values in arr
}
```